# MaskFormatter: only low letters from 1 to infinitely allowed

Tags: java, masking, maskformatter

I am searching for a "regular expression"/pattern for MaskFormatter where the only the first letter is Upper Case and the all other letters are low case

```
mf = new MaskFormatter("U([L]){1,}");
```

This code above wont work because it does not support regular expr. Is there another way?
How can I say that the low case letters can be 1 or infinitely.

Comment: The method used here does not support a regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Is there another way then?

Comment: You should look at implementing your own formatter, extending DefaultFormatter or AbstractFormatter.  I haven't looked at doing this myself yet, so don't know how difficult it would be.